# Could someone help me understand how the ACCELERATOR_KEY works in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, acceleratorkey

I am trying to understand how the ACCELERATOR_KEY is used and what it does.  I found a code example online that shows how it is used, but when I run the code nothing seems to happen.

If I had to guess it seems the ACCELERATOR_KEY allows the user to assign a keyboard command to something, but in this example when I press ‘A’, nothing happens.  Any ideas or explainations would be most appreciated!  Thank you!

```
    // w w w  .  java 2  s .c o  m

   import java.awt.BorderLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
   import javax.swing.Action;
   import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.KeyStroke;





     public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] a) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Action action = new ShowAction();
        JCheckBox button = new JCheckBox(action);

        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(350, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }

     class ShowAction extends AbstractAction {
       public ShowAction() {
         super("About");

         putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"));
         putValue(Action.NAME, "Go to number ");

      }
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
         System.out.println("About Swing");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I had to guess it seems the ACCELERATOR_KEY allows the user to assign a keyboard command to something

Correct.

However, if you read the `Action`API you will see that the `ACCELERATOR_KEY` is only used for components that extend `JMenuItem` (except for JMenu).

If you want to use "A" as a `KeyStroke` to invoke an `Action` for the `JCheckBox`, then you need to use `Key Bindings` to manually do the binding by using the `InputMap` and `ActionMap` of the check box.

Read the section from the Swing turtorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Note the tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Menus` and the demo code in that section demonstrates how to use an accelerator.

You can also try the `How to Use Actions` section. The Actions used in that demo are used by both a menu item and a button. You can try adding an accelerator the the Action to see the difference between the two components.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.